# #define macros for "static" for different contexts

Tags: c++, macros, keyword, semantics, preprocessor

I want to distinguish "static" keyword in the different contexts. What are possible drawbacks of doing

```
#define common static // class member
#define intern static // linkage
```

from technical and semantic perspectives.

Comment: Is "everyone who's going to deal with this code after you will hate you" a valid drawback? `#define intern static` is as bad as `#define BEGIN {`, except its meaning is even less obvious. I suggest getting used to the proper keywords, even if you don't like how they look.

Comment: Is your **only** goal to try to achieve more "clarity" ? If yes, It might be counter-productive. It's going to end up in someone of your team (possibly you) forgetting that those macros exist and then the code will get even more confusing. I think it would be fine if there was a way to "ban" a keyword and thus force people into using one of your macros instead of just ```static```.

Comment: It seems not a problem, if I work on my own project. And yes, ability to ban a word would be important in case you need to force people use it. But then you have to define another word for static duration context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use this approach, that if somebody, who has no idea what this means, will be really disoriented.
If you really want to use macros (Read this: https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Preprocessor_Macros), I'd advise you to use UPPER_CASE:

```
#define COMMON static // class member
#define INTERN static // linkage
```

If you use only caps, a person, that sees your code will know, that this are macros. This style is encouraged by the Google C++ style guide (https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Macro_Names).

From a technical perspective I would say there's no difference, as the C++ compiler won't see a difference, as the Preprocessor replaces your `common` and `intern` with `static`.